# Flash Plugin Crashes After 1 Second of Audio or Video Playback

Tags: sound, video, flash

This happens in all browsers, only for flash objects with multimedia content. Non-multimedia flash objects work just fine, until I try to access the Settings, at which point the whole object becomes unresponsive (but doesn't give me an error about crashing).

I was also having problems with my audio drivers today; I'm not sure if that's related. I fixed those problems by following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting), ending with this command:

```
sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
```

I've tried basically everything I can think of as well as everything suggested in forums, blogs, etc. and now I'm at my wits' end. Anybody know what's going on or how I can fix it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I'm running 11.10 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Go to Mozilla website for plug-ins. Install flash-aid or flash-video-replacer.

You can reset Firefox back to OEM settings:

Backup your profile

```
sudo cp ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini.bak
```

Then remove it

```
sudo rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
```

This will reset everything in firefox to default settings.

Comment: Already tried flash-aid, didn't fix the problem. I'll try the other one too.

Comment: flash-video-replacer allowed my to watch a youtube video in firefox. However, it did not fix flash. It only works for videos that it knows how to handle. Not a fix, more like a bandaid, and not a good one at that. Thanks for the suggestions, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu-restricted-extras, which installs the flashplugin-installer package, then it is using 32bit libs and isn't true 64bit.  Try removing it
`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge flashplugin-installer`

Enable the partner repository in your sources.list
`gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`  and look for

```
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
```

remove the # and save/exit
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

Comment: Good to know about `flashplugin-installer`. Still the same, though.

Comment: I guess it could be down to your video driver as well.  What chipset are you using?

Comment: Not sure. How would I find that out?

Comment: lspci | grep VGA

Comment: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)`

Comment: Figured it would be intel.  I have no solution other than maybe updating to the xorg edgers bleeding edge drivers.  There is a ppa.